# Installing SQLServer 2008 on WIndows Server Web edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

Have an option to choose either a windows SE or Web Edition to install, for my Web based application built on Asp.Net 3.5 Framework.

Question: Have noticed in some blogs they mentioned that, we cannot install SQL Server 2008 on a WebEdition. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly - it is not true, you can install STandard, Developer, Express, Enterprise (and may be Datacenter) editions of SQL Server @ Web edition of Windows Server 2008

You need something unusual?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean SQL Server 2008 R2, if so it can be installed on a web edition but you need a special version of SQL Server 2008 R2.

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#Web64